# Opal.rb anonymous function in native object

Tags: ruby, opalrb

Is it possible to somehow achieve methods/lambda assigned in Hash to compile to native functions in native object?
for example let

```
x = {foo: "foo", bar: ->{"bar"}}
```

I need that `x` to be compiled like such native object:
pseudo

```
x.to_n 
=>
Object {foo: 'bar', bar: function(){return "bar";}}
```

> OK THAT WORKS AS EXPECTED ALMOST

is there a way to transpile method to native function
e.g.

```
def foo
 'bar'
end
```

apply something like

```
(??:foo??).to_n
=>
function(){return "bar";};
```

?

Comment: I'm not a smart man((, everything works as expected

Comment: extra question added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to pass a *ruby method* as a callback to a *javascript function*, you could try something like this:

```
   x = { bar: method(:foo).to_proc }
   x.to_n
```

But bear in mind that this might not work as intended for class methods ( the context might change on *javascript*)

Another option is just wrap that method call on a lambda

```
   x = { bar: ->{ foo } }
   x.to_n
```

This seems a safer approach on my experience

---

EDIT:

My first answer just referenced `method(:foo)`, but when you call this you get a **Method** object which opal doesn't bridge properly to an anonymous function, so it would require you to use it like this on javascript:

```
  console.log(#{x.to_n}.bar.$call())
```

To have it work as a `function` you need it to be a proc, so the need to call `to_proc`, and again this will probably broke if its a instance method

```
  class Test
    def initialize
      @var = "baz"
    end
    def foo
      "bar #{@var}"
    end
  end

  t = Test.new
  x = { bar: t.method(:foo).to_proc }
  `console.log(#{x.to_n}.bar())` # bar undefined
  y = { bar: ->{ t.foo } }
  `console.log(#{y.to_n}.bar())` # bar baz
```

Comment: ``console.log(#{x.to_n}.bar())`` with method(:foo) is not compiled to legit function, but lamba works fine, does method(:foo) work in your code?